# Однородное подчинение придаточных

Tags: пунктуация

Могут ли при однородном подчинении придаточных использоваться разные подчинительные союзы? Например: "Он тщательно готовился к экзамену, понимая, какая ответственность лежит на нем и что учитель будет строг в своих оценках.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Могут. Ср.: ***Я не знал, куда мне идти и что теперь делать.***
 В моём примере оба придаточных предложения присоединяются к главному при помощи союзных слов, отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и относятся к одному глаголу ЗНАЛ - однородность налицо.

Ваше предложение построено не очень красиво: первое предложение присоединяется союзным словом КАКАЯ (местоимение относительное), на него падает логическое ударение,  а второе - союзом ЧТО. Поэтому однородность здесь не ощущается.

Ср.:***Он тщательно готовился к экзамену, понимая, какая ответственность лежит на нем и как учитель будет строг в своих оценках.*** Здесь уже оба союзных слова несут смысловую нагрузку степени, и всё выглядит очень гармонично.

Answer (score 4):

Он тщательно готовился к экзамену, **понимая**, **какая** ответственность лежит на нем **и что** учитель будет строг в своих оценках.

Это **однородные изъяснительные** придаточные, союзное слово "какая", союз "что".

**Определение.** Однородные придаточные  предложения относятся к одному и тому же главному предложению или **к одному и тому же слову** в главном (если придаточные распространяют не всё главное предложение, а одно его слово);
придаточные предложения отвечают **на один и тот же вопро**с, то есть это придаточные **одного и того же типа**.

Разные союзы/союзные слова могут быть **только в однородных придаточных с изъяснительным значением**, так как в этом случае от **общего опорного слова** в главном предложении ко всем придаточным можно задать **один и тот же вопрос:** знать(что?), мысль (какая?) и т.д.,  а союзы/союзные слова в придаточных могут быть разными.

Что касается придаточных другого типа, то для них разные союзы **вряд ли возможны.**

Answer (score 3):

> Могут ли при однородном подчинении придаточных использоваться разные
>   подчинительные союзы?

Могут. И в приведённом Вами предложении  —  тоже однородное подчинение придаточных.

Ср.:

***Я так и не понял 1/, в каком случае надо звонить 2/ и что надо сказать3.***

[**Из Литневской:**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm)

> В СПП с двумя и более придаточными возможны следующие способы связи
>   этих частей друг с другом:
>
> <...>
>
> 3) **однородное подчинение:** придаточные предложения являются
>   однотипными и относятся или к одному и тому же члену главного
>   предложения, или ко всему главному предложению в целом (их также
>   называют соподчинёнными придаточными). Между собой однородные
>   придаточные связываются сочинительной или бессоюзной связью
>   (интонационно):
>
> *Я так и не понял 1/, в каком случае надо звонить 2/ и что надо сказать3.*
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]